# Nicer way of checking JavaScript namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces

Now I have a module which follows a long chain of namespaces, for example:

```
TOP.middle.realModuleName = function () { /*...*/ }
```

I need to use this module on a page, and I'm not sure if this page has included the namespace Top.middle. So I would have to do something like:

```
if (typeof TOP !== 'undefined' && TOP.middle && TOP.middle.realdModuleName) {
    new TOP.middle.realModuleName();
}
```

I think the `if` statement looks really long and verbose. Anyone has suggestions on how to write a nicer parameter checking pattern for this case?

Comment: Wait, are you including this module in an external script or writing it on your own? If you are including it, you will have an error as soon as the function is defined if it’s namespace is not defined properly.

Comment: I'm including this module in an external script.

Comment: So, you’ll have an error thrown before even checking your namespace? How about checking the namespace before including the module?

Comment: There are some errors I intend to throw when the consumer does not use my module correctly. They won't be thrown before even checking the namespace. They will be thrown when this module is initialized. For example, when `new Top.middle.realModuleName(arg1, arg2)` is called, inside realModuleName will check if arg2 is passed (assuming arg2 is required). It arg2 is not passed, throw an error.

Comment: Yes, ok, but as soon as the consumer includes the module, an error will be thrown if the module is a part of a namespace that does not exists, am I right? I’m just trying to get my head around why you would want to validate the namespace before calling a method inside the namespace...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just encapsulate it in a TRY/CATCH?

```
try {
    return new TOP.middle.blablabla();
}
catch(err) {
    // oh no!
}

return null;
```

Comment: I like this answer more. Does it hurt the performance? Also, if there is any issue/error with the module `TOP.middle.blablabla`, would the try...catch mix the error with the not defined error?

Comment: Yes, if there is an exception within the constructor, then it WILL be caught in the try/catch.  That could be seen as a good thing too.  As for performance, I doubt that there would be a noticable difference, sure you could make a loop to execute this 1 million times, but rarely will a scenario like that happen in the real world.

Comment: Actually in my module `blablabla`, I intentionally throw some errors to warn the consumers of this module about the wrong usages. I don't really want to ignore these errors or make a long catch block for that  on that page.

Comment: @Grace: I think the general wisdom is that `try..catch` does not significantly hurt performance – unless an exception occurs, the same code is executed as if the `try..catch` wasn't there. It's safe to assume the overhead of setting the handler up is minimal compared to the code inside the `try` block.

Comment: @Matthew Given these answers, your answer is closer to what I want, which is something short. I will give yours the vote. I like and respect others' answers too. :)

Comment: The problem with the `try catch`  is not performance, it is the fact that if you add any other code inside of it, you'll be potentially catching the wrong error.

Answer (score 9):

Try this simple helper function:

```
function exists(namespace) {    
   var tokens = namespace.split('.');
   return tokens.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return (typeof prev == "undefined") ? prev : prev[curr];
   }, window);
}
```

It takes a `String` as input and will return the object if it exists. You can use it like this:

```
var module = exists("TOP.middle.realModuleName");
```

For example:

```
exists("noexist"); // returns undefined
exists("window"); // returns DOMWindow
exists("window.innerHeight"); // returns Number
exists("window.innerHeight.toString"); // returns Function
exists("window.innerHeight.noexist"); // returns undefined
```

It also works properly for expressions that evaluate to false:

```
testNum = 0;
testBool = false;
testNull = null;

exists("testNum"); // returns 0
exists("testBool"); // returns false
exists("testNull"); // returns null
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like this although it is prone to error if it receives some funky input:

```
if(check("TOP.middle.realModuleName")) {
  //exists
}

//namespace checking function
function check(ns) {

  var pieces = ns.split('.'),
      current = window;

  for(i in pieces) {    
    if(!(current = current[pieces[i]])) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: You can make this a lot shorter by setting `current=window` and then removing the first `if`. If you don't think it's too unreadable you could also put the `current=current[...]` assignment inside the remaining `if`. And we've cut the function length in half.

Comment: Hmmm, I was thinking about writing a utility to check. However, currently this page is only using this namespace chain once. Do I need to write more code (more code than the code I already have) to support this?

Comment: @davin I'm not sure why I didn't see that to begin with... thanks for your advice, I'm making the edit now

Comment: @Grace my best advice is to write the function.  If you have your own utility framework or collection of helper functions add it to that.  A lot of JS frameworks probably have this packed into them as well, so if you are using then check out the API.

Comment: You shouldn't have responded to me; now I spotted something more sinister: you should `var` the `i`, rather than make it global :)

Comment: Also, assume we are checking a `Boolean` or `Number` that is `false` or `0`, then the check will fail. We should handle this case too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a try/catch and look for '`not_defined`':

```
try {
    TOP.middle.realModuleName = function () { /*...*/ };
} catch(e) {
    if ( e.type == 'not_defined' ) {
        // exception
    }
    else {
        // throw other errors
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `new TOP.middle.realModuleName()` in the try block?

Comment: That works too, but defining a function in a namespace that does not exist is enough to throw errors, so why not do both at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole thing in one line this way:

```
TOP && TOP.middle && TOP.middle.realdModuleName && new TOP.middle.realdModuleName;
```

Note that your function will be run immediately.  If you want to store the function for later reuse, just assign it (`var module =`).  If the module function is not defined, then `undefined` is set/thrown away.

Comment: I understand your point, and why you use multiple &&. IMO, using too many && instead of if statement actually hurts code readability.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't agree with you there.  I find  this easier to read than multiple lines of code. But I understood that you were looking for something less verbose.  If that's not the case, then I suppose it's just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: After rereading your question, I can imagine that by verbose you don't mean too many lines, but rather too many if expressions.  In that case, I would personally vote for David's answer, but with an empty catch block: `try { new TOP.middle.realModuleName(); } catch(e) {}` Unless, of course, you need to do something if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I use a function that parses a namespace and creates it if it doesn't exist. Here is the function:

```
framework.namespace = function(baseName){
  var ns = baseName.split('.');
  var o = window;
  for (var i=0, l=ns.length; i < l; i++){
    o = o[ns[i]] = o[ns[i]] || {};
  }
  return o;
};
```

Then, before I need to use the namespace, I do this:

```
framework.namespace("TOP.middle.realModuleName");
TOP.middle.realModuleName = function(){...};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

The way that I learnt it was (**applies to namespace creation as well**):

```js
// Check if the com namespace does not exist:
if (!com) {
    var com = {};
}

// Check if your namespace does not exist:
if (!com.myNamespace) {
    var com.myNamespace = {};
}
```

---

### Some information that I learnt (so far)

According to a book that I'm reading, the `com` namespace is a container for commercial products (by that, I mean websites, libraries etc).

The namespace was originally created to hold domains. However, today you'll find `com.*` in libraries, databases or even frameworks!

> It is currently operated by [VeriSign](https://www.verisign.com), and has been in existence **for 33 years** now!

---

### Long answer

First, we need to make sure that the **main** namespace exists. We'll do this checking if `com` does not exist:

```js
if (!com) {
    var com = {};
}
```

`com` is the most common namespace to check. However, we can check **any** namespace.

> We could skip this part, but it would be *really* irritating to get all of your functions mixed up.

If `com` does not exist, then create it.

```js
var com = {};
```

Lastly, we need to check if `myNamespace` exists. We'll be using the same method for the `com`, but this time, we'll add `com.` before `myNamespace`.

```js
if (!com.myNamespace) {
    var com.myNamespace = {};
}
```

The reason why we add `com.` before our namespace declaration, is that the `com` namespace is made at the *second level* and myNamespace is made on the third level.

> I recommend that you add a Fourth level namespace for your project.
>   This will ensure that:
>
> - your project has it's **own** namespace (if myNamespace is taken).
> - your project will not be mixed in with other projects (e.g. com.projectA.other and **com.projectA.yourProject**).
> - your functions will not get mixed up (e.g. you have a function called write).

---

### Now, your code

You're nearly there! Here is how **I** would look at it:

```js
if (!TOP) {
    // Reinitialize your TOP Namespace here:
    var TOP = {};
}

if (!TOP.middle) {
    // Reinitialize your MIDDLE Namespace here:
    var TOP.middle = {};
}

if (typeof TOP.middle.realModuleName == "function") {
    new TOP.middle.realModuleName ();
}
else {
    // Redefine your function here (you never know ;) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to do that more quickly by:

```
           ?.
```

example:

```
const adventurer = {  name: 'Alice',  cat: {    name: 'Dinah'  }};
const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
```

more detailed answer: https://tc39.es/proposal-optional-chaining/#sec-scope